# Django Rest Framework Serializer lost ListField data during validation

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I want to serialize a list of strings as well as some other fields. Somehow it doesn't appear to be in validate data.

```
class OptionsSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    lst = serializers.ListField(
        serializers.CharField(),
    )
    field_a = serializers.CharField()
    field_b = serializers.IntegerField()
```

**Request payload:**

```
{"lst":["abc"],"field_a":"some text","field_b":1}
```

**Debugger output:**

```
ipdb> serializer.is_valid()
True
ipdb> serializer.validated_data
OrderedDict([('field_a', 'some text'), ('field_b', 1)])
```

Any ideas about why is it so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#listfield) says you need to set `child` keyword argument of ListField.

> child - A field instance that should be used for validating the objects in the list. If this argument is not provided then objects in the list will not be validated.

Try this:

```
lst = serializers.ListField(
    child=serializers.CharField()
)
```

Answer (score 1):

`child` is keyword argument, therefore you need to initialize the `ListField` like this:

```
 lst = serializers.ListField(
        child=serializers.CharField(),
 )
```